# Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy in https redirect unless I clean browser

Tags: angular, ssl, .net-core, cors, apigee

I have an angular + .net core 2.1 application. It works well when just use http, now I want to redirect to https.
However every time I got the error when I started the application to login

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at ’https://appgee.mycompany.com:5001/’ from
> origin ’https://app.mysite.com:5001’ has been blocked by CORS policy:
> The ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ header has a value
> ’https://app.mysite.com:5001’ that is not equal to the supplied origin

If I clean the browser data, then the error is gone. But it is inconvenient to user.
My code in .net core:

```
services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder => {
                builder
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials()
                .AllowAnyOrigin();
            })); 




app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

I use apigee to do authentication, in angular I set the request header for api request for apigee as(in interceptor):

```
SetHeaders: {
   Authorization: 'Bearer $ {token.access_token}',
   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
```

You see that I already allow origin both in front side and back end. But why it happens?

**UPDATE:**

Apigee target endpoint I have

```
<HTTPTargetConnection>
     <Properties/>
     <URL>http://app.mysite.com:5001</URL>
</HTTPTargetConnection>
```

Comment: why down vote? thanks let me know so I can update the post.

Comment: i suspect its something with apigee being misconfigured. Remove that layer and see if you still get the same error

Comment: @O.MeeKoh, I updated the apigee part.

Comment: you might have to create a proxy file to proxy your requests to that address

Comment: Sounds like a caching issue. You probably want to consider adding a `Vary: Origin` response header to the response. But it’s still odd that the origins in the error message are the same: *from origin ’https://app.mysite.com:5001’ has been blocked by CORS policy: The ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ header has a value ’https://app.mysite.com:5001’ that is not equal to the supplied origin*.

Comment: @sideshowbarker, how to add a `Vary: Origin` response header to the response in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
```

According to the discussion from https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/sep/26/aspnet-core-and-cors-gotchas

> @Kristian - the middleware *order* definitely matters, although you may be right that it has the important order is in the Configure() method, not ConfigureServices(). To be safe I make sure I have the CORS definition before MVC in both places. Checking now to see which one actually matters, or not at all. Several references mention this explicitly.

So I put UseCors in the first line of the methods.